# How could my cyborg live longer?

Tags: science-based, biology, science-fiction, xenobiology, robots

I have created a world where the main character is a cyborg, a petri dish with neurons inside a machine, the problem is most neuronal cultures only live for weeks, 60 days or  up to 5 years, that's what all the articles I've read say. How could I prolong the life of my cyborg/neurons?

Comment: Maybe you need source of cells that don't die so quickly in a culture medium...

Comment: (a) The [tag:science-based] and [tag:science-fiction] tags are mutually exclusive (read their roll-overs), please pick only one. (b) You've not provided nearly enough detail for a reasonably objective answer. You need to explain your cyborg tech and specifically what biological conditions are trying to be preserved. (c) Let me be honest - you didn't ask with the detail you're expecting in an answer. Why do you need it? You appear to be handwaving the cybog tech, why not the life expectancy tech?

Answer (score 9):

By building a structure that sustains the neural structures and keeps it active.

I dont know what articles you read since you didnt post them so I dont know what the problems were in those instances. But since those neural structures can function for years in humans (centuries in some other animals!) It should be possible to give them a framework where they last longer. The most likely culprits would be improper feeding (nutrients, vitamins, hormones etc) and being purposefully used. In biology "if you dont use it you lose it" is an important aspect to keep efficiency up and not keep feeding cells that dont serve a purpose. Neurons have a high plasticity, this is important in streamlining the brain's processes and switching tasks to things the brain is performing more often. So of the neurons arent used for specific neuron stuff they'll degrade naturally.

If you make sure the neurons can replicate (say stemcells are included that keep replenishing the neurons to facilitate their plasticity and natural death) and are properly fed and stimulated in their performance you can have a long lifetime for these cyborgs.

Answer (score -1):

Nanomachines can be used to repair neuronal cells by replicating and lengthen the lifespan of neurons.

They are small robots that can be programmed to perform specific tasks. E.g. create artificial cells, repair cells or modify the DNA which could help prolong life.